# Search array data based on multiple parameters in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React Project, I have an array of objects where I am displaying the values based on certain conditions. I'm able to populate the data with one parameter but, I also want to display with other parameter. Please go through the code below.

```
const users = [
    { name: "Jack", id: "1" },
    { name: "Lisa", id: "2" },
    { name: "Peter", id: "3" },
    { name: "Roman", id: "4" },
    { name: "Sarah", id: "5" },
    { name: "Eric", id: "6" },
    { name: "Fiora", id: "7" },
  ];

  const filterNames = ({ name }) => {
    return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  };
```

As you can see I'm filtering the array data with "name" parameter which searches exactly as expected but, want to populate records with "id" parameter, like it should work for both "name" and "id". Any appropraite solution highly appreciated.

Below is the stackblitz link for your reference

Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-search-filter-demo-fmkhv2?file=index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are using a string for the state: `searchValue`. Change it to an object `{id: '', name: ''}`.

This will help you filter based on both `id` and `name`.

```
const filterNames = ({ name, id }) => {
    return (
      name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
      id === searchValue.id
    );
  };
```

While setting the state value in your `SearchBar` component, you will need to pass both the id and name

```
 onChange={(e) =>
        props.onSearch({
          id: getId(e.target.value),
          name: e.target.value,
        })
      }
```

Probably using a utility function to get id of the searched value:

```
const getId = (searchValue) => {
    return props.data.find(
      (item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.id.includes(searchValue)
    )?.id;
  };
```

---

To be honest, this feels more of a hassle for such simple functionality.

You can simply use another state for displaying the filtered list instead of filtering it in real-time.

This is how I would do it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-search-filter-demo-qzp3kx?file=SearchBar.js,index.js

Answer (score 0):

The filter callback can do anything you want it to do, as long as it returns a truthy value for elements you wish to include.

```js
const filterNames = ({ name, id }) => {
  const maybeId = parseInt(searchValue, 10)
  return isNaN(maybeId)
    ? name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
    : id === searchValue
}
```